# Custom notification sound for a particular website only, opened on W10 PC using chrome or firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, notifications

I use chrome / firefox to open a particular website on my W10 PC. I want a custom notification sound to be played ***only*** for this particular website different from notification sounds from other apps/websites etc. Any solution ?